# Joda-time in grails 2.4.3 with Mysql ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport

Tags: mysql, jodatime, grails-2.4, schemaexport

I'm trying to run my app. I have a grails project 2.4.3 version and I'm using Hibernate4. 
In my BuildConfig.groovy file, I have:

```
    dependencies {
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
        compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0"
    }

   plugins {
       compile ":joda-time:1.5"
        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    }
```

And in my Config.groovy file I have:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime, class: org.joda.time.DateTime
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDurationAsString, class: org.joda.time.Duration
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentInstantAsMillisLong, class: org.joda.time.Instant
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentInterval, class: org.joda.time.Interval
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate, class: org.joda.time.LocalDate
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime, class: org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTime, class: org.joda.time.LocalTime
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentPeriodAsString, class: org.joda.time.Period
}
```

I copy a set of dominion class from another grails project but 1.3.5 version, I run the app and the tables was created but with errors:

```
Hibernate: alter table ventas_pago add constraint FK_6j2qual02owvkq48xga6fki9s foreign key (medio_pago_id) references medio_pago (id_medio_pago)
Hibernate: alter table ventas_pago add constraint FK_rbhjla1vjr4asrpryc4yy4wjv foreign key (id_venta) references venta (id_venta)
Hibernate: alter table ventas_pago add constraint FK_cs3k59ycva16s5r6iu8586em2 foreign key (id_ventas_pago) references entidad (id)
Error |
2015-03-05 10:01:32,859 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table ventas_pago add constraint FK_cs3k59ycva16s5r6iu8586em2 foreign key (id_ventas_pago) references entidad (id)
Error |
2015-03-05 10:01:32,859 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Anyone know Why this happening is?

Thank you for your time and your answer.